# R package installation when another package needed is imported but not depended

Tags: r, package

When I am writing an R package, there are several packages that I listed as `Import` instead of `Depend`.

My question is that, when people are installing my package from source, i.e. `install.packages('pkgNmae', repo=NULL, type="source")`, and **their computer does not have the necessary packages I imported pre-installed**, will the command `install.packages` recognize this? Will the user be able to use my package after installation?

I am not sure if I list these packages in `Import` they'll be automatically installed if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will be automatically installed if needed.  Imports and depends are identical for the purpose of installation - they only differ in their package-load-time behaviour.